# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS keeps failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, validation, select

I am not able to find the a true answer for my specific case and I can't figure out why I can't put 2 conditions in WHERE and how to fix it. I would like to check if a row with this 2 values exists in other table.

```sql
DECLARE @IsCanBeSharedValid INT = ISNULL((
    SELECT TOP 1 CrdTID, CrdTCanBeShared
    FROM [dbo].[IH_CardTypes_Cat] (NOLOCK)
    WHERE CrdTID = @TypeId AND CrdTCanBeShared = @CanBeShared
), -1)
```

Getting this error

Error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what your code should be doing.

Comment: Its not the `where` clause that is the problem, you are trying to assign 2 values to a single variable (`TOP 1 CrdTID, CrdTCanBeShared`) how do you expect that to work?

Comment: And stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You want to assign the variable `@IsCanBeSharedValid` with the value from which column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in the `where` clause, you are trying to put two values "CrdTID, CrdTCanBeShared" into your variable, which is wrong, the right and more clean way is:

```
DECLARE @IsCanBeSharedValid INT = ISNULL((
    SELECT TOP 1 CrdTCanBeShared
    FROM [dbo].[IH_CardTypes_Cat] (NOLOCK)
    WHERE CrdTID = @TypeId AND CrdTCanBeShared = @CanBeShared
), -1)
```